# Add single element to array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array containing:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create an array containing:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

That is, I want to add the first element on to the end of the array.

I have tried the obvious:

```
np.concatenate((a, a[0]))
```

But I get an error saying `ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions`

I don't understand this - the arrays are both just 1d arrays.

Comment: `np.insert([1,2,3], 3, 1)`

Answer (score 261, accepted):

`append()` creates a new array which can be the old array with the appended element.

I think it's more normal to use the proper method for adding an element:

```
a = numpy.append(a, a[0])
```

Comment: This command does not alter the `a` array. However, it returns a new modified array. So, if `a`  modification is required then `a = numpy.append(a,a[0])` must be used.

Comment: `np.append` uses `np.concatenate`.  It just makes sure the addon has one dimension.  The OP error was the `a[0]` has 0 dimensions.

Comment: Why append creates a whole new array if I just want to add one element?

Comment: I don't like the fact we need to call another function for such a simple command. It would be nicer if there was an inner method in the array itself like `a.append(1)`, `a.add(1)` or even something analog to lists like `a + [1]`

Answer (score 57):

When appending only once or once every now and again, using `np.append` on your array should be fine. The drawback of this approach is that memory is allocated for a completely new array every time it is called. When growing an array for a significant amount of samples it would be better to either pre-allocate the array (if the total size is known) or to append to a list and convert to an array afterward.

Using `np.append`:

```
b = np.array([0])
for k in range(int(10e4)):
    b = np.append(b, k)
1.2 s ± 16.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using python list converting to array afterward:

```
d = [0]
for k in range(int(10e4)):
    d.append(k)
f = np.array(d)
13.5 ms ± 277 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Pre-allocating numpy array:

```
e = np.zeros((n,))
for k in range(n):
    e[k] = k
9.92 ms ± 752 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

When the final size is unkown pre-allocating is difficult, I tried pre-allocating in chunks of 50 but it did not come close to using a list.

```
85.1 ms ± 561 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
np.concatenate((a, np.array([a[0]])))
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

concatenate needs both elements to be numpy arrays; however, a[0] is not an array. That is why it does not work.

Comment: Or, more simply `np.concatenate((a, [a[0]]))`. The list will get promoted to an array type automatically anyway, saving you some typing.

Answer (score 16):

This command,

```
numpy.append(a, a[0])
```

does not alter `a` array. However, it returns a new modified array. 
So, if `a` modification is required, then the following must be used.

```
a = numpy.append(a, a[0])
```

Answer (score 15):

`a[0]` isn't an array, it's the first element of `a` and therefore has no dimensions.

Try using `a[0:1]` instead, which will return the first element of `a` inside a single item array.

Answer (score 10):

```
t = np.array([2, 3])
t = np.append(t, [4])
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add an element use `append()`

`a = numpy.append(a, 1)` in this case add the 1 at the end of the array

If you want to insert an element use `insert()`

`a = numpy.insert(a, index, 1)` in this case you can put the 1 where you desire, using index to set the position in the array.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit overkill, but I always use the the `np.take` function for any wrap-around indexing:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.take(a, range(0, len(a)+1), mode='wrap')
array([1, 2, 3, 1])

>>> np.take(a, range(-1, len(a)+1), mode='wrap')
array([3, 1, 2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `a=[1,2,3]` and you want it to be `[1,2,3,1]`.

You may use the built-in append function

```
np.append(a,1)
```

Here 1 is an int, it may be a string and it may or may not belong to the elements in the array. Prints: `[1,2,3,1]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to format code and then update your answer so that it is more readable :) Also this is a very old question with an accepted answer, better to answer some new ones