# Add single element to array as first entry in numpy

Tags: numpy

How to achieve this?
I have a numpy array containing:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I want to create an array containing:

```
[8, 1, 2, 3]
```

That is, I want to add an element on as the first element of the array.

Ref:[Add single element to array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332841/add-single-element-to-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic operation is `concatenate`:

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])
np.concatenate([[8],x])
# array([8, 1, 2, 3])
```

`np.r_` and `np.insert` make use of this.  Even if they are more convenient to remember, or use in more complex cases, you should be familiar with `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.insert()`. The docs are here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy.insert

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy's [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), a short-cut for concatenation along the first axis:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.r_[8, a]
>>> b
array([8, 1, 2, 3])
```