# How to add element to matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I saw many posts on the same issue but using `numpy.array`, whereas here I am talking about `numpy.matrix`. How can I add an element to a matrix?

For example:

```
my_matrix = [[1 2 3 4 5]]
```

How can I make it:

```
my_matrix = [[1 2 3 4 5 6]]?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add single element to array in numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332841/add-single-element-to-array-in-numpy)

Comment: I talk about matrix not array

Comment: You didn't create `my_matrix` with this statement, did you: `my_matrix = [[1 2 3 4 5]]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since matrices are very constrained in numpy (and probably you would be better off if you avoid them), they are very picky compared to regular numpy arrays. You can use a bit verbose command

```
np.concatenate((my_matrix,[[6]]),1)
```

or use the horzcat

```
np.c_[my_matrix,[[6]]]
```

Comment: With `concatenate` (and friends), a `matrix` imposes the same constraints as a 2d array.  `my_matrix.A` requires `[[6]]` as well.

Comment: `hstack([np.arange(5),6])` works when adding to a 1d array, but not with a 2d or matrix.  But `np.c_[my_matrix,6]` works - it is able to expand the `6` to 2d.

Comment: @hpaulj the last one is bradcasted. It probably won't work for different shapes.

Comment: `np.c_` passes the `6` through `np.array(6,ndmin=2)` to make it match the matrix dimensions.  That's not the same as broadcasting.  In any case, a good numpy programmer should know how to adjust dimensions themselves and use plain `concatatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj my bad broadcasting has a special meaning in python i meant 2D'd. But for your later remarks, I'm pretty much the antagonist. Nobody needs to be forced to do something in a particular way. Numpy is exceedingly clunky no matter how useful it is. It really needs some overhauling at some point.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I did.

```
>>>n = np.matrix('1,2,3,4,5')
>>> n
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>>np.insert(n,5,6)
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

For multidimensional arrays, you'll have to mention the horizontal index as well as the vertical index, otherwise the resultant matrix will be flattened.

```
>>> n = np.matrix('1,2;4,5')
>>> n
matrix([[1, 2],
        [4, 5]])
>>> np.insert(n,1,6) #Here 1 indicates the index in the flattened matrix.  
matrix([[1, 6, 2, 4, 5]])
```

In the documentation, the vertical index is mentioned as "axis".

```
>>> n = np.matrix('1,2;4,5')
>>> n
matrix([[1, 2],
        [4, 5]])
>>> np.insert(n,1,6, axis=1)
matrix([[1, 6, 2],
        [4, 6, 5]])
>>> np.insert(n,1,(67,78), axis=1)
matrix([[ 1, 67,  2],
        [ 4, 78,  5]])
```

[Here's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) the link to the documentation.