# Appending a number from a list to an empty numpy array.

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append a number to a numpy array. This seems like a simple task (and I have seen and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332841/add-single-element-to-array-in-numpy)), but somehow they are not being appended.

```
newlist = np.array([])

for i in range(15, 15+number):

    number =  myList[i][1];
    np.append(newlist,[number]) 
    print newlist
```

I believe it might have to do with the fact that myList is a normal list that contains both strings and numbers. Should I cast it to a number first or something?  myList:

```
[['started recording', '38:20.4', '\r\n'], ['stopped recording', '42:46.1', '\r\n'], ['participant number', '41', '\r\n'],...
```

Comment: Some assignment: `newlist = np.append(newlist,[number]) `

Comment: Take another look at the docstring for [`numpy.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).  In particular, see the "Returns" section, which notes that `append` does not work in-place.

Comment: Oh my, of course. That is too silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, you're not the first to make this mistake.  Perhaps the *first* line of the docstring should be "Copy `arr` and append `values` to the end.", or something like that.

Comment: It's especially confusing because the normal list doesn't require this. Do you want to post this as an answer?