# Parsing a .txt file in Python to a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, parsing

I have a bunch of .txt files with metrics with the following formatting:

```
|Jaccard: 0.6871114980646424 
|Dice: 0.8145418946558747 
|Volume Similarity: -0.0006615037672849326 
|False Positives: 0.18572742753126772 
|False Negatives: 0.185188604940396
```

I would like to read them all (around 700) and store each value to a numpy array, so I could get statistics like average jaccard, average dice, etc.

How could I do that?

Comment: Do you want this in a single, 2D array, with name and value?  If so, loop around as you read the file, and append each element.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332841/add-single-element-to-array-in-numpy.   Or, you you want to have each element of the 700 files available for later processing?

Comment: Reading the lines, split and parse the numbers.  What you show doesn't imply any array structure, so we can't help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach. The result is a dictionary with with all metrics in an array e.g.

```
 {"|Jaccard" : array...,
....}
```

Code might look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import os

pathtodir = "filedir"
d = {}
for file in os.listdir(pathtodir):
    with open(file, "r") as of:
        lines = of.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        k, v = line.split(": ")
        if k in d.keys():
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v]

for k in d:
    d[k] = np.array(d[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `genfromtxt()` from numpy. See https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html.
Use':' as delimiter and extract a string followed by a float.

`data = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=":", dtype='S64,f4')`

Parsed the file and produced following `data`:

```
(b'|Jaccard',  6.8711150e-01) (b'|Dice',  8.1454188e-01)
 (b'|Volume Similarity', -6.6150376e-04)
 (b'|False Positives',  1.8572743e-01)
 (b'|False Negatives',  1.8518861e-01)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to open each file and save its content in a `pandas.DataFrame`. The clear advantage respect to `numpy.array` is that it is easier to perform later statistics. Check this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

pathtodir = r'data' # write the name of the subfolder where your file are stored
df = pd.DataFrame()
file_count = 0

for file in os.listdir(pathtodir):
    with open(os.path.join(pathtodir, file), 'r') as of:
        lines = of.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        header, value = line.split(':')
        value = float(value.replace(' ','').replace('\n', ''))
        if header not in df.columns:
            df[header] = ''
        df.at[file_count, header] = value
    file_count += 1

for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(float)
```

With 4 example files, I get this dataframe:

```
print(df.to_string())

    Jaccard      Dice  Volume Similarity  False Positives  False Negatives
0  0.687111  0.814542          -0.000662         0.185727         0.185189
1  0.345211  0.232542          -0.000455         0.678547         0.156752
2  0.623451  0.813345          -0.000625         0.132257         0.345519
3  0.346111  0.223454          -0.000343         0.453727         0.134586
```

And some statistics on the fly:

```
print(df.describe())

        Jaccard      Dice  Volume Similarity  False Positives  False Negatives
count  4.000000  4.000000           4.000000         4.000000         4.000000
mean   0.500471  0.520971          -0.000521         0.362565         0.205511
std    0.180639  0.338316           0.000149         0.253291         0.095609
min    0.345211  0.223454          -0.000662         0.132257         0.134586
25%    0.345886  0.230270          -0.000634         0.172360         0.151210
50%    0.484781  0.522944          -0.000540         0.319727         0.170970
75%    0.639366  0.813644          -0.000427         0.509932         0.225271
max    0.687111  0.814542          -0.000343         0.678547         0.345519
```